# Use Logical OR with FIND in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, find, logical-operators

I want to find the index of some specific numbers says 100, 120 from a series of 100 numbers.

How to use `FIND` statement with Logical `OR` for it

Here is what I am trying

```
idx=find(data(:,1)==120 || data(:,1)==100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct, just replace **||** operator with **|** operator:

```
idx=find(data(:,1)==120 | data(:,1)==100);
```

In MATLAB, **||** is a boolean or operator, and **|** [perform logical OR of arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/or.html) (which is what you want).

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering whether I can use `Logical OR` with `FIND` in MATLAB, though I am not getting how to do that, I could do the same using `ismember`

```
idx=find(ismember(data(:,1), [100;120]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Logical OR](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/or.html) with | to find index of some specific number. The symbols | and || perform different operations in a MATLAB® application. The element-wise OR operator described as |. The short-circuit OR operator is ||.

you can use this,

```
idx=find(data(:,1)==120 | data(:,1)==100);
```